# How to communicate between independent components in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm newbie in React.JS and trying to understand the following thing. Imagine that I have two components: two HTML text inputs; what I want to achieve is the following: when a user changes the text in first text field - changes appears at the same time in a second text field; and vice versa - when a user changes the text in second text filed - the change also appears in the first one. What is the right way to do it in a react way? What should be written in the `onChange` handlers?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I like an event-driven approach. It's easy to implement a Pub/Sub pattern either using a little library (such as [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS)) or rolling your own with native events.

I wrote a little more about the latter here:
http://maketea.co.uk/2014/03/05/building-robust-web-apps-with-react-part-1.html#component-communication

Answer (score 2):

As long as both your form inputs are (1) [controlled inputs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and (2) have a `value` property pointing to the same data, any change to that data will update both inputs.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var SyncEdit = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { text: "" };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  },

  handleChange: function(evt) {
    this.setState({text: evt.target.value});
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<SyncEdit />, document.body);
```

Here's [a JSFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/2K5qX/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/2K5qX/

Comment: Brandon, thank you for you answer. But what if I have these two inputs in completely different components? How to establish communication in this case?

Comment: @ArtemVorobyev You usually find some component (normally near the top of your component hierarchy) or some shared model object and have it "own" the data, which gets passed to child components via properties.

Comment: @ArtemVorobyev to get more separation between the components, take a look at the [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html) architecture pattern for React. It would be overkill for a single string, but if, say, one component was an unread messages count and the other was a message inbox, then it would likely be useful.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This is not communication between two independent components. This is just one component (SyncEdit).

Comment: @RosdiKasim I'll get a better example in there, but the answer is the same: have shared state somewhere in a parent, that passes the content as props, as well as a shared change handler that gets passed around.

Comment: Hi, forgive me if I am wrong, but from what I understand, independent components do not share a common parent, otherwise they are just sub components of a (one) component (the parent). I think the `PubSubJS` as suggested by @i_like_robots fits the bill.